# Extend ApplicationUser how to set correctly relationship from shared project

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am using ASP.NET Identity 2.0. Currently I would like to extend `ApplicationUser` (renamed `AspNetUsers` to `Users`) by table `UserDetails` like `FirstName` etc.

What's my issue?
I have separated class library project which stores EF Model. I don't like to generate another EF Model (if its not necessary).

I have in SQL Server relationship between Users table and `UserDetails` table, that's all alright. Unfortunately in ASP project Users table is somewhere deep hard-coded in `IdentityUser`. That means I have `ApplicationUser` which inherits `IdentityUser`.

What am I trying is in `AppDbContext`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    // Ignore columns
    builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Ignore(c => c.PhoneNumberConfirmed);

    // Rename tables
    builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users");
    builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles");
    builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>().ToTable("IdentityRoleClaims");
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>().ToTable("IdentityUserClaims");
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>().ToTable("IdentityUserLogins");
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>().ToTable("IdentityUserTokens");

    // Relationship
    builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
        .HasOne(p => p.UserDetails)
        .WithOne(i => i.Users)
        .HasForeignKey<Shared.Database.UserDetails>(u => u.UserID);
}
```

Problem is on last line in `WithOne(i => i.Users)`, `i.Users` is not `ApplicationUser`. Funny thing is that `ApplicationUser` has same properties like `i.Users` :D

So I only need to know how to correctly convert it to make relationship.

Any ideas how to solve this? Or any advice how to do it another way?

Shared project is used by 1 additional project (WCF) so I can't put there inheriting from `IdentityUser` :/

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I understand it, you want to map two different objects to one and the same database table and also map another entity FK to that table. Adn you have no problem with the first part, but having troubles with the second:

> Problem is on last line in `WithOne(i => i.Users)`, `i.Users` is not `ApplicationUser`. Funny thing is that `ApplicationUser` has same properties like `i.Users` :D

I see two solutions.

1. Remove the navigation property from the `UserDetails` class and simply use in both places `WithOne()`.
2. In case you need that navigation property, you could use approach similar to the Identity class structure as follows:

Let say the `UserDetails` class that you have currently in the shared project looks like this:

```
public class UserDetails
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    // other properties ...
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; } // the problematic navigation property
}
```

You can convert it to a generic class:

```
public class UserDetails<TUser> where TUser: class
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    // other properties ...
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public TUser User { get; set; }
}
```

and let the old non generic class simply inherit from it:

```
public class UserDetails : UserDetails<User> { }
```

Now everything in the shared project EF model should be as before, so the other (WCF) project using it should not be affected.

I guess you already are getting the point. In ASP project, you would just create another class:

```
public class ApplicationUserDetails : UserDetails<ApplicationUser> { }
```

and map it to the `UserDetails` table similar to how you mapped `ApplicationUser` to `Users`:

```
builder.Entity<ApplicationUserDetails>().ToTable("UserDetails");
```

Then change the `UserDetails` navigation property in the `ApplicationUser` class to:

```
public ApplicationUserDetails UserDetails { get; set; }
```

and finally set up the relationship w/o any problem:

```
builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
    .HasOne(u => u.UserDetails)
    .WithOne(d => d.User)
    .HasForeignKey<ApplicationUserDetails>(d => d.UserID);
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, unfortunately it is not the way how to do it, because there will always come some error with entity relationship. I have to redesign it completely. Anyway thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome, glad it helped. Although I wished it to be a real solution to the issue, not sure what are the implications with your real case, but I suppose you know better :)

Comment: Well the thing is that asp.net core don't support ado.net at it not works really well with basic entity framework how I thought. So my next steps is to generate database model based on entity framework core which should solve those troubles :)